# Can i use css like as javascript?

Tags: css

Friends,
can i use css as a nested functions and how to get the current css properties of element like as follow

```
.button1:active 
{
  #button2
  {
    width:width+20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can but with LESS, SASS or other similar tools. Go to http://jsbin.com/ open the CSS tab, click the arrow next the CSS tab  and play around

Comment: There are no functions in CSS. You should describe the desired effect, not some invented syntax that definitely isn’t CSS. And it would be illogical to “get the current css properties of element” when setting the property on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with standard CSS.

You can do.

```
.button1:active #button2 {
    width:20px;
}
```

However you can in [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [SCSS](http://nex-3.com/posts/96-scss-sass-is-a-css-extension).

With LESS you could do.

```
@elementWidth: 20px;

.button1:active {
    #button2 {
        width: @elementWidth + 20px; //Resulting width would be 40px
    }
}
```

Comment: `width:width+20px;` is invalid CSS declaration.

Comment: @Pavlo sorry copy and paste issue :)

Comment: I believe it's not the same thing author is asking: apparently he wanted to *increase* width by 20px, not set it to 20px.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like:

```
.button1:active #button2{
    width:20px;
}
```

Use CSS pre-processors [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted because it makes more sense than the other answer with invalid CSS. I'll upvote.

Comment: @BeatAlex merely a copy and paste issue.