# CSS Structure my code

Tags: css

Is there a way to structure a css-file in a way like this?:

```
a:link {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal
  }
}
```

So I want a normal link to be underlined and bold, but when I hover over it, it shouldn't be underlined and bold, but it should still have the same color. (This is a simple example just for explanation)

EDIT: I am/was looking for a way without sass or less

Comment: Yup But U Must Use CSS Less

Comment: @Dinesh Anything that can be written in Less can also be written in plain CSS; Less compiles to plain CSS after all. You cannot write it *exactly* like this, but there's no need to anyway. Even in Less this means something different than what OP actually wants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use css like as javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302316/can-i-use-css-like-as-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal
}
```

All `a` elements will be red and bold. Specifically `a:hover` elements will also have no text-decoration and the font-weight is overridden to `normal`. You're not trying to deal with "parents and children" where, just with more specific *states* of an element.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use this way. For the title thing, I did not know how to call it, so I thought it might be similar to the parent child association where the child has the same attributes as its parents. But I edited the title now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as inheritance in CSS, but you can do :

```
a:link, a:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was partially mentioned in the comments but I believe it deserves its own post.

You'd use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide/) (or LESS, but I find the former much easier) to write out your code and then a compiler like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) to compile it into regular CSS.

This way your code becomes:

```
a:link {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal
  }
}
```

And it will work as intended.

Comment: `&:hover` will compile to `a:link:hover`, which is not what's intended…

Comment: It is a possibility, but I  was looking for a way without sass or less